# Caulking around tub

Tags: bathtub, caulk

I've got a tub that kind of looks like this: http://inspectapedia.com/plumbing/Spa_Jacuzzi_137_DJFs.jpg

I am replacing the caulk, and noticed that on the far side, the gap is about 1/4" in height (from the tile to the bottom of the tub. If I put any weight on it at all, water in the tub, or just body weight, the gap disappears as the tub gets pushed flush to the tile.

Wondering how best to deal with this.  I have no access to that side of the tub from the access panel, and lifting the tub out is not possible.

Thoughts?

Comment: Can you check if both tub and surface are horizontal, so we could now which solution to suggest?

Comment: If you mean level... the tile surface is perfectly level in all places.

Comment: And how bout tub? Is it also perfectly leveled in all places? Also when you say "level" do you mean horizontal? Sometimes it can have a slope.